# Is there a way of adding values into a page of a 3d array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array, insert

I would like to insert values from one 1d array into a 3d array like this, but I have no idea how to do this.

I've tried to insert these values directly into the array itself, but with little succes. I tried using: np.insert.

If I take these two arrays for example:

```
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([[[0,0],[0,0]],[[1,1],[1,1]]])
```

I would like to insert a into b[0], and get a result as follows:

```
[[[0,0,1],[0,0,2]][[1,1][1,1]]]
```

Comment: You're output is not a valid numpy array. All inner arrays must have the same dimensions

Comment: Yes, in my case I would like to add the rest of the data later on when the program knows what the data will be that needs to be added at that point... should I then fill the rest with zeros or negatives?

Comment: If you know how large your array is going to end up being you can make an array of zeroes and substitute the values later.

Comment: Right, I will try that. I am inserting extra data into a larger data set for a nn. This will work I think, thank you!